# admin_head-post.php only works after publish / update

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I have made a custom post type with some admin back-end. Currently I am calling scripts using the hook

```
admin_head-post.php
```

but this only seems to fire once a custom-post type has been created (on publish) or updated.

What is a better hook that runs on a specific admin page but when a new post is being initially created as well as updated / published etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single hook for both, the new post page is `admin_head-post-new.php`.